# How to quickly add rules to iptables from blocklists?

Tags: bash, firewall, iptables

I am using Ubuntu Server 14.04 32bit for the following.

I am trying to use blocklists to add regional blocks (China, Russia...) to my firewall rules and am struggling with the length it takes my script to complete and understanding why a different script fails to work.

I had originally used http://whatnotlinux.blogspot.com/2012/12/add-block-lists-to-iptables-from.html as an example and tidied up / changed parts of the script to pretty close to what's below:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Blacklist's names & URLs array
declare -A blacklists
blacklists[china]="http://www.example.com"
#blacklists[key]="url"

for key in ${!blacklists[@]}; do
  #Download blacklist
  wget --output-document=/tmp/blacklist_$key.gz -w 3 ${blacklists[$key]}
  iptables -D INPUT -j $key #Delete current iptables chain link
  iptables -F $key #Flush current iptables chain
  iptables -X $key #Delete current iptables chain
  iptables -N $key #Create current iptables chain
  iptables -A INPUT -j $key #Link current iptables chain to INPUT chain
  #Read blacklist
  while read line; do
  #Drop description, keep only IP range
  ip_range=`echo -n $line | sed -e 's/.*:\(.*\)-\(.*\)/\1-\2/'`
  #Test if it's an IP range
    if [[ $ip_range =~ ^[0-9].*$ ]]; then
    # Add to the blacklist
    iptables -A $key -m iprange --src-range $ip_range -j LOGNDROP
    fi
  done < <(zcat /tmp/blacklist_$key.gz | iconv -f latin1 -t utf-8 - | dos2unix)
done
# Delete files
rm /tmp/blacklist* 
exit 0
```

This appears to work fine for short test lists, but manually adding many (200,000+) entries to iptables takes an EXORBITANT  amount of time and I'm not sure why?  Depending on the list I have calculated this taking upwards of 10 hours to complete which just seems silly.

After viewing the format of the iptables-save output I created a new script that uses iptables-save to save working iptables rules and then appends the expected format for blocks to this file, such as: *`-A bogon -m iprange --src-range 0.0.0.1-0.255.255.255 -j LOGNDROP`*, and eventually uses iptables-restore to load the file as seen below:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Blacklist's names & URLs arrays
declare -A blacklists
blacklists[china]="http://www.example.com"                           
#blacklists[key]="url"

iptables -F # Flush iptables chains
iptables -X # Delete all user created chains
iptables -P FORWARD DROP # Drop all forwarded traffic
iptables -N LOGNDROP # Create LOGNDROP chain
iptables -A LOGNDROP -p tcp -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Denied TCP: " --log-level 7
iptables -A LOGNDROP -p udp -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Denied UDP: " --log-level 7
iptables -A LOGNDROP -p icmp -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Denied ICMP: " --log-level 7
iptables -A LOGNDROP -j DROP # Drop after logging

# Build first part of iptables-rules
for key in ${!blacklists[@]}; do
  iptables -N $key # Create chain for current list
  iptables -A INPUT -j $key # Link input to current list chain
done

iptables-save | sed '$d' | sed '$d' > /tmp/iptables-rules.rules # Save WORKING iptables-rules and remove last 2 liens (COMMIT & comment)

for key in ${!blacklists[@]}; do  
  #Download blacklist
  wget --output-document=/tmp/blacklist_$key.gz -w 3 ${blacklists[$key]}
  zcat /tmp/blacklist_$key.gz | sed '1,2d' | sed s/.*:/-A\ $key\ -m\ iprange\ --src-range\ / | sed s/$/\ -j\ LOGNDROP/ >> iptables-rules.rules
done
echo 'COMMIT' >> /tmp/iptables-rules.rules
iptables-restore < /tmp/iptables-rules.rules
# Delete files
rm /tmp/blacklist* 
rm /tmp/iptables-rules.rules 
exit 0
```

This works great for most lists on the testbed however there are specific lists that if included will produce the ***iptables-restore: line 389971 failed*** error, which is always the last line (COMMIT).  I've read that due to the way iptables works whenever there is an issue reloading rules the error will always say the last line failed.

The truly odd thing is that testing these same lists on Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 64bit the second script works just fine.  I have tried running the script on the Desktop machine, then using iptables-save to save a "properly" formatted version of the ruleset, and then loading this file to iptables on the server using iptables-restore and *still* receive the error.

I am at a loss as to how to troubleshoot this, why the initial script takes so long to add rules to iptables, and what could potentially be causing problems with the lists in the second script.

Comment: Either add an `echo started cmd iptables ....; iptables ... ; echo done cmd iptables ...` in your first code's inner loop or use `set -vx` to visually confirm where the delay is. I could see that given the rule size that you seem to have, that running all of those commands might take a while. Can't help (at all) on your 2nd idea, but given that it is so much faster, it makes sense to try to fix that. Given the SA nature of your problem space, you might consider flagging your question and having it moved to `http://serverfault.com` . Good luck.

Comment: I've previously added an echo to display which rule the loop was currently adding, the only delay seems to be the speed with which these commands can be run.

I just ran the second script on a virtual machine with a FRESH 14.04.1 Ubuntu Server 32bit install and it works just fine.

Which caused me to update all packages on the physical test machine and try again, still failing!

Comment: hmmm. OK, so you're sure the slow machine's hard-drive doesn't have some bad sectors, or other problems that would cause this? Do you have the same amt disk free on both machines. Same RAM profile on both machines? Do "scrub" tests show any weaknesses in disk or RAM? Finally, could you add an extra disk on that machine or just swap it out with a known good disk? Seems like you would have thought of all of this. +1 for persistence and patience! Good luck!

Comment: Not sure but you could be reaching a limit of some sort for iptables and your OS version.  You might want to look at using Geoip via ipset OR xtables-addons (if your kernel supports them.)  More info in old posts I wrote: http://web-tech.ga-usa.com/2011/09/linux-geoip-firewall-via-iptables-xtables-addons/ and http://web-tech.ga-usa.com/2011/09/linux-geoip-firewall-via-iptables-using-ipset/.  :)

Comment: @shelter, to clarify, if by the "slow" machine you mean a machine taking a long time to add the rules manually using the actual iptables -A command rather than iptables-restore, any of my test machines (virtual or physical) have a very lengthy duration.

The limit, memory or other was a thought, however the iptables-restore script works fine on a VM with the same OS and less memory!  I'd looked into ipsets but I have some more reading to do to fully grasp.  My concern was that surely firewall rules of this magnitude have been done in the corporate world and I'm unsure of the "correct" approach

Comment: you wrote "My concern was that surely firewall rules of this magnitude have been done in the corporate world ", .... I originally wrote "Given the SA (sys admin) nature of your problem space, you might consider flagging your question and having it moved to http://serverfault.com . Good luck" . Might be time to ask to have this moved, or rewrite for serverfault from an SA point of view. Good luck!

Comment: Just in case anyone wonders why doing 200'000 lines of `iptables` is slow: `iptables` doesn't actually change the netfilter tables in memory; rather, it downloads them all, do the requested changes, and replaced the existing netfilter tables in one go. If you need to change lots of lines, it will be much faster to edit the output of `iptables-save` with all the changes you want, then replace the netfilter tables using `iptables-restore`.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to block a multitude of IP Addresses, use `ipset` instead.

Step 1: Create the IPset:

```
# Hashsize of 1024 is usually enough. Higher numbers might speed up the search,
# but at the cost of higher memory usage.
ipset create BlockAddress hash:ip hashsize 1024
```

Step 2: Add the addresses to block into that IPset:

```
# Put this in a loop, the loop reading a file containing list of addresses to block 
ipset add BlockAddress $IP_TO_BLOCK
```

Finally, replace all those lines to block with just **one** line in netfilter:

```
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -m set --match-set BlockAddress src -j DROP
```

Done. `iptables-restore` will be mucho fasta.

***IMPORTANT NOTE:*** I *strongly* suggest NOT using a domain name to be added into netfilter; netfilter needs to first do a DNS Resolve, and if DNS is not properly configured and/or too slow, it will fail. Rather, do a pre-resolve (or periodic resolve) of domain names to block, and feed the found IP addresses to the "file containing list of addresses to block". It should be an easy script, invoked from crontab every 5 minutes or so.

---

***EDIT 1:***

This is an example of a cronjob I use to get `facebook.com`'s address, invoked every 5 minutes:

```
#!/bin/bash
fbookfile=/etc/iptables.d/facebook.ip
for d in www.facebook.com m.facebook.com facebook.com; do
    dig +short "$d" >> "$fbookfile"
done
sort -n -u "$fbookfile" -o "$fbookfile"
```

Every half hour, another cronjob feeds those addresses to `ipset`:

```
#!/bin/bash
ipset flush IP_Fbook
while read ip; do
    ipset add IP_Fbook "$ip"
done < /etc/iptables.d/facebook.ip
```

*Note:* I have to do this because doing `dig +short facebook.com`, for instance, returns *exactly ONE* IP address. After some observation, the IP address returned changed every ~5 minutes. Since I'm too <s>lazy</s> occupied to make an optimized version, I took the easy way out and do a flush/rebuild only every 30 minutes to minimize CPU spikes.

Comment: About the hashsize, it should be equal to the total number of IPs expected rounded up to the next power of two if you want the fastest possible search. But that eats a lot of memory. Most people can make do with 1024 (the default). [Some additional info](http://www.odi.ch/weblog/posting.php?posting=738).

Comment: @AlexisWilke interesting... thanks for the tip! I guess I'll just use 1024 with a note that the size can be made higher for faster, at the cost of more memory.

Answer (score 2):

The following is how I ended up solving this using ipsets as well.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Blacklist names & URLs array
declare -A blacklists
blacklists[China]="url"
# blacklists[key]="url"
# etc...

for key in ${!blacklists[@]}; do
  # Download blacklist
  wget --output-document=/tmp/blacklist_$key.gz -w 3 ${blacklists[$key]}

  # Create ipset for current blacklist
  ipset create $key hash:net maxelem 400000
  # TODO method for determining appropriate maxelem

    while read line; do
    # Add addresses from list to ipset
    ipset add $key $line -quiet
    done < <(zcat /tmp/blacklist_$key.gz | sed '1,2d' | sed s/.*://)

  # Add rules to iptables
  iptables -D INPUT -m set --match-set $key src -j $key # Delete link to list chain from INPUT
  iptables -F $key # Flush list chain if existed
  iptables -X $key # Delete list chain if existed
  iptables -N $key # Create list chain
  iptables -A $key -p tcp -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Denied $key TCP: " --log-level 7
  iptables -A $key -p udp -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Denied $key UDP: " --log-level 7
  iptables -A $key -p icmp -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Denied $key ICMP: " --log-level 7
  iptables -A $key -j DROP # Drop after logging
  iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set $key src -j $key
done
```

I'm not wildly familiar with ipsets but this makes for a much faster method of downloading, parsing and adding blocks.

I've added individual chains for each list for more verbose logging that will log which blocklist the dropped ip is coming from should you have multiples.  On my actual box I'm using around 10 lists and have added several hundred thousand addresses with no problem!

Answer (score 0):

Donwload Zones

```
#!/bin/bash
# http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/
zone=/path_to_folder/zones
if [ ! -d $zone ]; then mkdir -p $zone; fi
wget -c -N http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/all-zones.tar.gz
tar -C $zone -zxvf all-zones.tar.gz >/dev/null 2>&1
rm -f all-zones.tar.gz >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Edit your Iptables bash script and add the following lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
ipset=/sbin/ipset
iptables=/sbin/iptables
route=/path_to_blackip/

$ipset -F
$ipset -N -! blockzone hash:net maxelem 1000000
for ip in $(cat $zone/{cn,ru}.zone $route/blackip.txt); do
    $ipset -A blockzone $ip
done
$iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -m set --match-set blockzone src -j DROP
$iptables -A FORWARD -m set --match-set blockzone dst -j DROP
```

example: where "blackip.txt" is your own ip blacklist and "cn,ru" china-russia"

Source: [blackip](https://github.com/maravento/blackip)

Comment: Note that adding each IP one by one with `ipset -A` is slow. You should create a file with all the `-A ...` arguments, then use `ipset restore ...`. That does ONE send of all the IPs to the kernel. Much faster.

Comment: @AlexisWilke Sounds good, but not very clear. Could you expand your answer?

Comment: Try the `ipset save ...` to see the file format. You want to create such a file, then run the `ipset restore`. It's very similar to the `iptables-save` and `iptables-restore`.